# Converting binary blob private key to base64 format

Tags: binary, openssl, cryptography, base64

So, I have a private key in binary blob format which looks like some encrypted junk. Now, what should I do in order to transform that into a correct looking private key which is usable by `openssl` ?

For instance, I want it to be in `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- some base64 -----END PRIVATE KEY-----` format. 
How is it possible ?

Comment: The binary might be in DER format. To find out, do `openssl pkey -inform der -in key.blob -text -noout` (where `key.blob` is the name of your binary file) and see if openssl is able to understand the content.  If that works, then the command to translate the DER file into a file in the format you want (which is called PEM format) would be `openssl pkey -inform der -in key.blob -outform pem -out key.pem`

Comment: Encode your private key using PKCS #8. The `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` is PEM encoding from [RFC 1421](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1421) and friends.

Comment: I already did that. fails

Comment: @ottomeister I get an error ```Unable to load key
140149540597952:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:101:
```

Comment: That means that your binary blob does not contain a private key encoded in DER format.  Until we know the format of your blob, we can only guess at possible solutions.

Comment: What are the other formats except DER ? @ottomeister

Answer (score 1):

Convert the binary blob to string or base64 decode the whole thing and see what it produces. If it is gibrrish, you would need to see if it is encoded differently or if it is encrypted. If later, you need to decrypt.
It is difficult to provide a concrete answer without having more details on the data format.

Comment: I tried something like `cat blob.bin | base64 > secret.key` and appending begin and end tags. But failed.